# Node | Wiring GET to successfully Posted Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, express

Trying to learn Node.

I have a post request that sends out weather metrics such as *timestamp, temperature, dew point, and precipitation.*

I'm able to successfully post a request with the following `req.body`

I have a store handling the business logic i.e:

```
/* measurement-store */

export function addMeasurement(measurement) {
  // cache results on a new object
  const measurements = { timestamp: measurement.timestamp.toISOString() }

  if (measurement) {
    for (const [metric, value] of measurement.metrics.entries()) {
      measurements[metric] = value // retrieve metric values
    }
    return measurements
  } else {
    throw new HttpError(501)
  }
}
```

This how the endpoint is consuming it

```
/*measure-routes.js*/

import * as store from './measurement-store'
****

// Handle POST Measurements
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const measurement = parseMeasurement(req.body) // method to parse the req.body

  store.addMeasurement(measurement)

  res
    .location(`/measurements/${measurement.timestamp.toISOString()}`)
    .status(201)
    .json({
      message: 'Measurements were successfully created',
      measurement
    })
})
```

As you'll see here the POST call is successful:

[image]

**My problem is not being able to fetch and GET the newly created Object**

I'm unable to wire the correct business logic in my store so that when I pass a GET call i.e. `http://localhost:9000/measurements/2015-09-02T16:00:00.000Z`

The results are processed with a `status 200`

This is my GET route

```
/*measure-routes.js*/

router.get('/:timestamp', (req, res) => {
  const result = store.fetchMeasurement(new Date(req.params.timestamp))
  if (result) res.json(serializeMeasurement(result))
  else res.sendStatus(404)
})
```

This is how the `serializeMeasurement()` massages the data.

```
function serializeMeasurement(measurement) {
  const out = { timestamp: measurement.timestamp.toISOString() }

  for (const [metric, value] of measurement.metrics.entries()) {
    out[metric] = value
  }

  return out
}
```

Can you help me apply the correct GET business logic here

```
/* measurement-store */

export function fetchMeasurement(timestamp) {
  if (timestamp) {
    console.log('FETCH', timestamp) // => 2015-09-02T16:00:00.000Z
  }
  throw new HttpError(501)
}
```

Comment: Why are you throwing in `fetchMeasurement()`.  The code that is calling it isn't catching that exception.  So, that `/:timestamp` route will NEVER work.

Comment: Also defining a `/:timestamp` route like that matches ALL top level GET requests on your server so you can't have any others.  That's not a very good design idea either.

Comment: Very newbie to Node here... Could you please show me an example of a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you throwing in `fetchMeasurement()`? The code that is calling it isn't catching that exception. In addition `fetchMeasurement()` isn't returning anything yet the code that is calling it requires a return value.

So, that `/:timestamp` route will NEVER work.  It will throw and never send a response.

I'm not sure I understand the entire problem you're asking about, but you can begin to fix `fetchMeasurement()` like this:

```
/* measurement-store */

export function fetchMeasurement(timestamp) {
  if (timestamp) {
    console.log('FETCH', timestamp) // => 2015-09-02T16:00:00.000Z
    // return something useful here
    return someValue;
  } else {
    return null;    // caller will send response error if returned value is null
  }
}
```

You will have to fill in the part where `fetchMeasurement()` returns a useful value because the calling code:

```
const result = store.fetchMeasurement(new Date(req.params.timestamp))
```

expects a useful return value.

Comment: Thank you jfriend00. I can get rid of the `Throw`. Just didn't wanna edit the question and lose the meaning of our comments. Ok, so my problem is not being able to know what's is the business logic for `someValue` and what that should look like on this case in order to successfully make a GET call based on the routes. Also, how do you suggest me wiring the Route then?

Comment: @NullisTrue - I can't help you with the correct business logic for `fetchMeasurement()`.  Only you can know what that is.  The way you're calling the function, you pass it a timestamp and it is supposed to return a value that you then pass to `serializeMeasurement()` whose code you do not show so we have no idea what it expects.

Comment: @NullisTrue - You are correct to not edit the code in the question and change the meaning of what you originally asked.  What else are you trying to ask for help with?

Comment: Ok 1- If my POST is successful. How can I GET that data passing the GET request as `http://localhost:9000/measurements/2015-09-02T16:00:00.000Z`, following your train of thought what should be the business logic to  `someValue` in lieu of the current code? 2- How else do you suggest me modifying the `get route`

Comment: Sry didn't see your first comment... I've added the `serializeMeasurement()` to the post

Comment: @NullisTrue - Still not sure what you're asking for.  If you want to POST some data and then later be able to GET that data back, you have to store it somewhere persistently on your server and have some sort of request key that allows you to identify which data is being requested (perhaps that's a timestamp) so when the GET request comes in, you can look for the appropriate data in some data store.

Comment: That's exactly the secret sauce. However, I'm not sure how to accomplish such effort. I was under the impression that I'd be able to store the request inside `fetchMeasurement()`